# Remove only whitespaces between words, but leave \n

Tags: php, regex

I am using `PHP 7.4.1` and want to remove double/triple/n-th whitespaces only between two words.

I tried:

```
<?php

$str = "Hello World!
\n

This is my  input  string.";

$str1 = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);

echo $str1;

echo "\n############################### \n";

$str2 = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu', ' ', $str);

echo $str2;

echo "\n############################### \n";
```

This on the one hand removes the whitespace, but on the other hand removes the **two** `\n`.

I would like to have the following output:

```
Hello World!


This is my input string.
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You could match 2 or more horizontal whitespace chars `\h{2,}` instead of `\s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundaries:

```php
$str = "Hello World!\nThis is my  input  string.";
$output = preg_replace("/\b[ ]{2,}\b/", " ", $str);
echo $str . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
Hello World!
This is my  input  string.
Hello World!
This is my input string.
```